# How to convert non-ordinal date from string to datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am no stranger to converting strings to dates in Python; but I can't seem to figure this out.

I am using `datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")` where timestamp is 1/6/2016 15:14.

Does anyone know how to convert this, since the date is single digit, rather than 01/06/2016 etc.  The datetime module continues to error out, saying it is not the correct format.

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior: There's no format string for that, so I think the only option is to manually add a 0 to single digit days.

Comment: Perhaps this is due to Python's "Beautiful is better than ugly" philosophy which sees 1/6/2016 is not as beautiful as 01/06/2016 (more symmetrical). =) But since "beauty is in the eyes of the beholder", so we cannot really blame it.

Comment: Rats.  Thanks for saving me from the frustration of figuring it out.

Comment: To correct us all, there is a way.  Lowercase corresponds to single digits, and uppercase responds to double digits, for future reference.  My mistake actually was not with my day or month, but my year, which was y, not Y.

Comment: I think you mean that `%m` and `%d` work with or without zero-padding. You can't just capitalize them (as evidenced by you using `%M` in your string for minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("1/6/2016 15:14", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

below is the console output:

```
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("1/6/2016 15:14", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 6, 15, 14)
```

Comment: you should mention the difference between `%y` and `%Y` (with a link to the docs)

Comment: Oh! just missed that! sorry and thank you for this good catch!